# How to use placeholder in CachedNetworkImage?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add a placeholder of a progress bar while image is loading but for some reason it does not work.

My code

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: 'url',
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use progressIndicatorBuilder when image is loading like this

```
progressIndicatorBuilder:
                          (context, url, downloadProgress) => Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
```

or try this for placeholder

```
placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

Comment: Dart Latest version does not need the new keyword. can you pls remove it?

Answer (score 2):

`Placeholder` property of `CachedNetworkImage` is **function** with **args** `(BuildContext context, String url)` and **returns** `Widget`.

Try this approach :

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    imageUrl: 'imageUrl',
      fit: BoxFit.cover,

    placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
      color:  Colors.transparent,
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      child: SpinKitFadingCircle(
        color: ColorConstants.colorPrimary,
        size: 30,
      ),
    ),

    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset(
       placeHolderImage,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

to

```
placeholder: (context,url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

Comment: This solution is already provided in another answer. If you have any different solution please mention it. If there is any change/extension required to the original answer, then edit it.